# Strange behaviour of an elementary CUDA code.

Tags: c, cuda

I am having trouble understanding the output of the following simple CUDA code. All that the code does is allocate two integer arrays: one on the host and one on the device each of size 16. It then sets the device array elements to the integer value 3 and then copies these values into the host_array where all the elements are then printed out.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int num_elements = 16;
  int num_bytes = num_elements * sizeof(int);

  int *device_array = 0;
  int *host_array = 0;

  // malloc host memory
  host_array = (int*)malloc(num_bytes);

  // cudaMalloc device memory
  cudaMalloc((void**)&device_array, num_bytes);

  // Constant out the device array with cudaMemset
  cudaMemset(device_array, 3, num_bytes);

  // copy the contents of the device array to the host
  cudaMemcpy(host_array, device_array, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // print out the result element by element
  for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i)
    printf("%i\n", *(host_array+i));

  // use free to deallocate the host array
  free(host_array);

  // use cudaFree to deallocate the device array
  cudaFree(device_array);

  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is 50529027 printed line by line 16 times.

```
50529027
50529027
50529027
..
..
..
50529027
50529027
```

Where did this number come from? When I replace 3 with 0 in the  `cudaMemset` call then I get correct behaviour.  i.e. 
0 printed line by line 16 times.

I compiled the code with `nvcc test.cu` on Ubuntu 10.10 with CUDA 4.0

Comment: Don't cast malloc()s return value; include <stdlib.h>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `cudaMeset`works like the standard C `memset`- it sets byte values. From the CUDA documentation:

```
cudaError_t cudaMemset( void * devPtr, int value, size_t count)
```

> Fills the first count bytes of the memory area pointed to by devPtr
>   with the **constant byte value** `value`.

If you want to set word size values, the best solution is to use your own memset kernel, perhaps something like this:

```
template<typename T>
__global__ void myMemset(T * x, T value, size_t count )
{
    size_t tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    size_t stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    for(int i=tid; i<count; i+=stride) {
        x[i] = value;
    }
}
```

which could be launched with enough blocks to cover the number of MP in your GPU, and each thread will do as many iterations as required to fill the memory allocation. Writes will be coalesced, so performance shouldn't be too bad. This could also be adapted to CUDA's vector types, if you so desired.

Answer (score 7):

I'm no cuda expert but 50529027 is 0x03030303 in hex. This means `cudaMemset` sets each `byte` in the array to 3 and not each `int`. This is not surprising given the signature of cuda memset (to pass in the number of bytes to set) and the general semantics of memset operations.

**Edit**: As to your (I guess) implicit question of how to achieve what you intended I think you have to write a loop and initialize each array element.

Comment: In CUDA, you would do it by writing a kernel to set the values directly in the GPUs memory, not use a loop.

Comment: @talonmies: But it's still a loop ;)

Comment: Note: you could call cuMemsetD32() to set the integer value.  This is one of the few driver API functions that is not wrapped in a CUDA runtime function.  Since it is a simple wrapper for a kernel invocation, it won't have any bad interactions with the CUDA runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`memset` sets bytes, and integer is 4 bytes.. so what you get is 50529027 decimal, which is 0x3030303 in hex... In other words - you are using it wrong, and it has nothing to do with CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic memset shortcoming; it works only on data type with 8-bit size i.e **char**. This means it sets (probably) 3 to every 8-bits of the total memory. You can confirm this by a simple C++ code:

```
int main ()  
{    
    int x=16;
    size_t bytes = x*sizeof(int);

    int *M = (int*)malloc(bytes);
    memset(M,3,bytes);


    for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i) { 
        printf("%d\n", M[i]); 
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

The only case in which memset works on all data types is when you set it to 0. (it sets every byte to 0 and hence all data to 0). If you change the data type to **char**, you'll see the desired output. cudaMemset is ditto copy of memset with the only difference that it takes a GPU pointer in input.

So memset or cudaMemset probably sets every byte to the integer value (in your case 3) of whole memory space defined by the third argument regardless of the datatype.

**Tip:**

Google: **50529027 in binary** and you'll get the answer :)